# jQuery: SUM fields if they are filled out

Tags: jquery, html, input, sum

I want to SUM 4 fields with jQuery and put the decimal (example: 0.5) in one other field.

The first field is a required field the others not, if the first is filled out only this value must be set in result field.

If any of the other fields are filled out then the sum of these field must be put on the result field.

I have this input field, as 'LiquidRatioTotal' is the result field:

```
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatio1" id="LiquidRatio1" required>
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatio2" id="LiquidRatio2">
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatio3" id="LiquidRatio3">       
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatio4" id="LiquidRatio4">                                               
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatioTotal" id="LiquidRatioTotal" required>
```

How can i realize that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can attach an `input` event handler to all the ratio inputs which adds up all their values. To make that easier you can add a class on the inputs to group them. If the input does not have a value provided, you can default the value to `0` for the calculation. Also note that I made the 'total' field `readonly`, as I assume you do not want users to be able to edit that. Try this:

```js
$('.liquidRatio').on('input', function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.liquidRatio').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0; 
  }); 
  $('#LiquidRatioTotal').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatio1" id="LiquidRatio1" class="liquidRatio" required />
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatio2" id="LiquidRatio2" class="liquidRatio" />
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatio3" id="LiquidRatio3" class="liquidRatio" />
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatio4" id="LiquidRatio4" class="liquidRatio" />
<input type="text" name="LiquidRatioTotal" id="LiquidRatioTotal" required readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

First, removing the result input attribute 'required', and replacing it with 'readonly' (since it's not for writing, but for reading).
Second, some JS :

```
$('input[id*="LiquidRatio"]').on('input',function() {
  var sum=0;
  for (var i=1;i<=4;i++) {
    if ($('#LiquidRatio'+i).val() && !isNaN($('#LiquidRatio'+i).val())) {
        sum+=parseFloat($('#LiquidRatio'+i).val());
    }
  }
  $('#LiquidRatioTotal').val(sum);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
var Sum = 0;

$('input[id^="LiquidRatio"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "" && $(this).attr('id') != 'LiquidRatioTotal') {
        Sum = Sum + parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
});

$('#LiquidRatioTotal').val(Sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys, i found another good methode that works:

```
$(document).on("change", ".liquidRatio", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".liquidRatio").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".totalRatio").val(sum.toFixed(1));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you requiring a `jQuery` answer?  This isn't 1997.  The vanilla javascript answer is shorter, easier to understand, and doesn't require a library dependency.

I'll assume you want to hit all inputs on the page.  If not, change the selector to hit only the ones you want (easiest way is to add a class to the relevant inputs, then select for that class instead.)

First, you need a function that will get all of those numbers for you

```
const getNums = () => [... document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(i => i.value);
```

Summing functions are easy:

```
const sum = arr => arr.reduce( (a,b) => a+b, 0 );
```

Next, you need a function that does something with those values.  You didn't say what, so, I'll just sum them and write them to some `<div id="output">` that I'm assuming exists.

```
const outNums = nums => document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = sum(nums);
```

Finally, you'll need to decorate the inputs so that they know to actually do this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').onchange = () => outNums(getNums());
```

The final code:

```
const getNums = ()   => [... document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(i => i.value || 0),
      sum     = arr  => arr.reduce( (a,b) => a+b, 0 ); 
      outNums = nums => document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = sum(nums);

document.querySelectorAll('input').onchange = () => outNums(getNums());
```

Please put jquery away now.  It's time to move on.